# Why does std::span overload the function call operator for indexing?

Tags: c++, c++20

Edit: this overload has been removed from the standard now, it seems.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/operator_at):

> ```
> constexpr reference operator[](index_type idx) const;
> constexpr reference operator()(index_type idx) const;
> ```
>
> Returns a reference to the `idx`-th element of the sequence. The
>   behavior is undefined if `idx` is out of range (i.e., if it is less
>   than zero or greater than or equal to `size()`).

It makes sense to overload `operator[]` for indexing, as a span represents an object that can refer to a contiguous sequence of objects, but why is `operator()`, the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator), also overloaded for the same purpose? I don't believe there's anything similar to this in the standard library.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is there because `mdspan`, [a not-yet-accepted multi-dimensional span type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0009r4.html), uses `operator()` for indexing. After all, `operator[]` only takes one index, while `mdspan` needs multiple indexing.

So for the sake of allowing these two types to have as similar an interface as possible, `span` also allows `operator()`.

Note that using `operator()` is a common convention in C++ for multi-dimensional indexing. Eigen and Boost both use it, as do many others.

Comment: Will `std::span` be able to be multidimensional?

Comment: @MárioFeroldi: No; if it were, we wouldn't need `mdspan`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a very sound motivation. After all, you could have a 1-dimensional mdspan, couldn't you?

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, but a 1D `mdspan` would not be a `span`. `span` ensures that the data is contiguous; `mdspan` *doesn't*. An `mdspan` can have iterators that skip elements. And while a 1D `mdspan` would be required to be tightly packed, it still wouldn't have `span`'s interface members (like `data`) since it's based on a template that doesn't assume tight packing. To do what you suggest would require that a 1D `mdspan` would have a template specialization for the 1D case, and this specialization would basically be `span`. What's the point?

Comment: @NicolBolas: My point is that I don't feel like the interface of span should be as similar as possible to mdspan. But that's just a persona opinion.

Comment: @einpoklum I've heard that the committee simply forgot it was there until late at Jacksonville, so they kept it in for the time being rather than hold the proposal back. The intention is to remove it before C++20 IIUC

Comment: @Justin: That seems like another answer actually.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't have a good enough source to make into an answer though. Just a comment made in the cpplang slack

Answer (score 10):

From the [relevant proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r6.pdf):

> span also overloads 
>   operator()
>    for element access, to provide compatibility with code written to 
>   operate against 
>   view.

The `view` has been renamed to [`mdspan`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0009r4.html) by now, which is not standardized yet.

As correctly noted in Nicol Bolas' answer, `mdspan` will use `operator()` to accept multiple indices.